# JavaScript obj[property] throwing "property not defined " instead of giving undefined value

Tags: javascript, object

```html
 <html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function Person(name, age) {
                this.name = name;
                this.age = age;
            }
            var person = new Person('Tom', 25);
            document.write(person[name] + ' age is ' + person[age]);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I am new to javaScript , in the above code I am aware of the error that *person['name']* and *person['age']* is right syntax, but my confusion is 
***person[name]*** giving **undefined** value but 
***person[age] throwing error*** **in browser console**.
Please help me understanding this behaviour.
**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

In `person[name]` you're trying to use variable `name` as key (accessor). `name` is not initialized, so you actually tell the interpreter to give you the value of `person["undefined"]`. In this case you have to use the dot notation: `person.name`. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

let person = new Person('Tom', 25);

try {
  console.log(person[name]);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
}

try {
  console.log(person[age]);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
}

console.log(person.name + ' age is ' + person.age);

// this would work:
const name = "name";
const age = "age";
console.log(person[name] + ' age is ' + person[age]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Hi Kooiinc , here I am assigning the values  through `let person = new Person('Tom', 25);` , but why it is is still throwing error? Why it is throwing error for `name` variable , but not for `age` when called individually like `person[name] `and `person[age]`

Comment: You are creating an *instance* of `Person` with *properties* `name` and `age`. Assigning the *variables* `name` and `age` is something diffferent. `person[age]` will not work if the *variable* `age` is not assigned, I assure you.

Comment: Yeah , You are right, but here `person[name]` giving `undefined` value but `person[age]` throwing error in browser console. `person[name]` must give an error , right? why that behaviour?

Comment: `person[name]` is *not* returning `undefined`. See adjusted code: both `person[name]` and `person[age]` will throw a `ReferenceError` (meaning something like: "This is the JS-interpreter: I don't know the variable `name` or `age` you are using here").